# How do I merge fields on update in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, upsert

Given a document structure in MongoDB

```js
{
    _id: "5d305779fc12b358849fae2c",
    externalID: 551,
    title: title,
    owners: ["John"]
}
```

I would like to perform update with upsert based on externalID. So if externaID is the same like in the new document it should only update owners field and add new owner, if not found create new document.

The result should look like:

```js
{
    _id: "5d305779fc12b358849fae2c",
    externalID: 551,
    title: title,
    owners: ["John", "new name"]
}
```

I'm trying to do it in one query, as data comes from API with multiple records by user/owner.
Is it possible or should I search for each externalID and if so update 
accordingly?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you need? `db.my_collection.update(
    {
        externalID:my_id
    }, {
        $push:{
            owners:"new_Owner"
        }
    }, {
        upsert: true
    }
)`

Comment: Not really, because if it's not found it will create document just with id and owners only.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out, with help of the comment from @Rakshith Sm

```js
db.collection("my_collection").updateOne(
    { _externalID: y_id},
        {
          $set: {
            title: my_title,
          },
          $addToSet: { owner: new_owner}
        },
        { upsert: true }
    );
```

$addToSet takes care about possible duplicates